# SearchView Not call onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

"Error" Well Strange Other times I've done it and never tive this problem ...

My searchview not call onOptionsItemSelected if i put "appname:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" on menu.

Manifest

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
 <activity
            android:name=".DashBoardActivity"
            android:label="">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

dash_board.xml (menu) (if I retreat actionViewClass he calls(onOptionsItemSelected ), but if i put he dont call)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appname="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.servic.DashBoardActivity" >


           <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          appname:showAsAction="always"
          appname:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

             <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        appname:showAsAction="always"/>



</menu>
```

DashBoardActivity

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dash_board, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id)
        {
        case R.id.action_search:
            mSearchView
            .setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (hasFocus) {
                        ToastMensagem("Digite um endereço.");
                    } else {
                        BuscarEndereco(mSearchView.getQuery().toString());
                    }
                }



            });
            break;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

The error is, not call onOptionsItemSelected, i need manipulate searchview

Comment: You didn't actually tell us what error you had...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know its too late now,but i am still writing answer if anyone else find it helpful in future.
Yesterday i came into same problem and i solved it by changing the following line in menu xml file

```
appname:showAsAction="always"
```

to

```
appname:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
```

you have to add `collapseActionView` in `appname:showAsAction` along with `always`to enable onOptionsItemSelected on searchView

Comment: Oh my god!  This solved the entire thing for me!  WTF? Why did it work? I had tried both `ifRoom` and    `always`  but only    `always|collapseActionView`  works. Please any explanations?

Comment: Its sept 2016 and this issue still persists, thanks for the solution!

Comment: Functionality is described in https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views#view-expansion

i fear the answer is, an action is not the option, and if you define an actionLayout or even actionViewClass you have something different. An ActionViewClass and even actionLayout results in an expandable action which first click is always "expand" but not onOptionItemSelected

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I add collapseActionView to the menu item the action bar title is hidden on search view click. This is the reason why I was searching for a way to leave it as

```html
android:showAsAction="always"
```

with onOptionsItemSelected funcionality. If anyone finds anything, please let me know! :)